# registration system using python

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, for-loop

I'm trying to solve a problem for the Online Judge. The problem is to make a program in which the user enters a name or any string and if string is not found in a list or a database it prints "OK", but if it's a repeat then make a new entry with the same name user entered but a "1" concatenate to it. For example if user entered **abc**, if it's repeated print **abc1**, and if it's been repeated before print **abc2**, and so on.

To do that I wrote the following code:

```
n=int(raw_input()) # number of testcases
counter=0
listaa=[] # list to save
comp=[]
for x in xrange(n):
    listaa.append(raw_input())
    for i in listaa:
        if i not in comp:
            print 'OK'
            comp.append(i)
        elif i in comp:
            counter+=1
            print "{}{}".format(i,counter)
```

If I input:

```
3    # number of test case
abc  # user string or name or anything
abc  # its repeated
def  # new one
```

I get this strange output which illustrates the problem:

```
OK   # first one and not repeat so print ok no problem
abc1 # it print abc1 ok no problem
abc2 # but why it print it twice
abc3 # for the third and new input it print abc3?
abc4 # and 4
OK   # and finally ok that I want but the above I don't want and instead
     # I want only "ok", and why it entered to elif clause if the first 
     # condition is true?
```

I use `elif`. From what I understand that if an `if` condition is not true, it moved on to the `elif`. Is that not correct? Anybody have a solution to this? I attempted to use a function but when I use `return` in it the loop stops.

Comment: Add a print statemen at the start of the for loop below 'for i in listaaa', print out i and listaa and comp, then maybe you will work out what you are doing wrong. Also FYI your 'elif i in comp' can be replaced with 'else' because the test i in comp' is the inverse of 'i not in comp' in the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not understanding your output.

```
OK
```

is printed after the first string is inserted

```
abc1
abc2
```

Are printed after the second string is inserted. comp already contains "abc" from the the previous iteration, and listaa = ["abc", "abc"] the for loop goes over every element in listaa and checks if it exists in comp - they both do so you get 2 prints.

and

```
abc3
abc4
```

are actually printed after you input

```
def
```

You have another issue in that you have a global counter so if you were to enter

```
4
abc
abc
def
def
```

you would get the wrong count for def.

The following code will solve both problems:

```
n=int(raw_input()) # number of testcases
db = {}
for x in xrange(n):
    s = raw_input()
    if s not in db:
        db[s] = 0
        print 'OK'
    else:
        db[s] += 1
        print "{}{}".format(s,db[s])
```

Comment: this work and accepted when i put the code of @zetysz it get time Time limit exceeded your code is perfect and work faster how you make that can you Guide me for a book or where you learn to do that and many thanks to you bro